# Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord Association Issues : Queries Not Being Made Properly (singular vs. plural?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

First post I've ever felt I had to make here, normally my questions are answered by just reading other posts but this time I think I'm in too deep to find the proper answer, I've been looking for quite a while. I may have multiple issues going on in my code.

I'm a novice with RoR, just started working with it the last couple of months. I'm attempting to run a test query to make sure my associations are working properly, and based on the errors I'm getting, I feel like I've messed up something simple. I'm setting up a couple of tables for a webapp, I'll focus on 2 tables for now because a fix to this can be applied elsewhere afterwards.

Pertinent information:

-I'm using Devise for user authentication

-I have a pto_requests_controller.rb and registrations_controller.rb (registrations is used with devise as a user controller)

-In the database, the table names are 'users' and 'pto_requests'

I have a pto_request model (filename is 'pto_request.rb'):

```
class PtoRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

And a user model (filename is 'user.rb'):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pto_requests
end
```

To create associations in the database, I used this migration:

```
class AddUsersToPtorequests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :pto_requests, :users, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

The foreign key was created in the 'pto_requests' table and called 'users_id'

I can query the tables individually with no issues, but once I try to access data like, for example, user.fname through pto_requests, it errors out. As an example query I've tried:

```
<%= PtoRequest.joins(:user)
.select('user.fname as user_name').first.user_name%>
```

I receive the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user.fname' in 'field list': SELECT  user.fname >as user_name FROM `pto_requests` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = >`pto_requests`.`user_id` ORDER BY `pto_requests`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

My current theory is it has something to do with an issue in the end of the generated SQL syntax as it is looking for 'user_id' but this does not exist, only 'users_id' does. Any help is greatly appreciated, and if any more information is required please let me know.

Comment: The table `user` does not exists, it is called the `users` table (notice the plural). Use `[...].select('users.fname [...]` instead

Comment: I did try that and I get a slightly different error message:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'pto_requests.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT  users.fname as user_name FROM `pto_requests` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `pto_requests`.`user_id` ORDER BY `pto_requests`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: According to the documentation, you should use the singular version of `users` for the `add_reference` call: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference . You should rollback that migration (so that the column is dropped), rewrite the code to change `users` to `user` in the migration file and re-run the migration.

Comment: Why don't your migrate with `belongs_to :pto_requests` ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference kind of failsafe

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this earlier as well but after receiving a new error related to nil value I now realize I had to go into my database and manually enter some values, as changing the column removed the old values causing this. I would like to test my other tables as well but I have a feeling I made this mistake in multiple places.

Comment: @Ant-IWH if you are sure that a `PtoRequest` must be associated to a `User`, then you should remove the `optional: true` of the `belongs_to` so that it is validated at each create/update of a `PtoRequest`.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes I am sure, but when I do this I receive this: 1 error prohibited this pto_request from being saved:
User must exist

from what I found in other posts, adding the optional: true line fixed that. The user does exist, and if I add optional:true, it saves to the database properly. If you know why this may happen maybe I can fix it in a different way then. Thank you again for all of your help, I appreciate it

EDIT: Disregard, I am dumb. Needed to remember to add 'user_id' to the controller parameters rather than 'users_id'

Comment: Well, using `optional: true` makes Rails skip the validation of the existence of the associated record (in this case, a User record). As you made Rails skip this existence check, you allowed you app to save data associated to non-existing Users. When you create/update a `PtoRequest`, you must associate an existing User to it. The primary issue had to be fixed, not worked-around.

Comment: I edited my last comment but I was too slow, I said: Disregard, I am dumb. Needed to remember to add 'user_id' to the controller parameters rather than 'users_id'. it works without optional:true.

Answer (score 0):

You have missunderstood the associations completely.

`belongs_to` creates a one-to-one or one-to-many association and places the foreign key column on this models table:

```
class PtoRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

This association thus will reference `pto_requests.user_id`. You have added the foreign key to the wrong table.

To generate the correct migration run:

```
rails g migration add_user_to_pto_requests user:references
```

The enitity you are referencing should always be singular.

Comment: Hi, as I understand it I believe I have already done that migration  properly now thanks to the above comment, 'user_id' is in 'pto_requests' currently after my migration i created. I am unable to mark his comments as the answer though because they were comments and not a question answer.